# no .vec files after createsamples OpenCV - Haar Training

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

i need your help :)  today i trained possitive image and negative image for HAAR detection. I followed this command below :

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt\ -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000\ -numNeg 600 -w 80 -h 40 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024\ -precalcIdxBufSize 1024
```

(from CodingRobin)  on my terminal, it seems "Done".
 But there's no .vec files in samples directory. Can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 0):

`opencv_traincascade.exe` USES the vec file. You must call the `opencv_createsamples.exe` instead.

The command line should look like:

```
opencv_createsamples.exe -info positives.txt -vec samples.vec -w 24 -h 24 -num 4455
```

for your number of samples and width/height

positives.txt should look like (each line):

```
#path #numberOfObjects #xObj1 #yObj1 #widthObj1 #heightObj1 #xObj2 #...
```

for example:

```
image1.png 1 0 0 84 84
image2.jpg 1 100 130 128 128
image3.png 2 10 30 50 50 300 100 101 101
```

etc.

After that you can train by calling opencv_traincascade with your parameter list and you'll get a .xml file as result.